# MPMoviePlayerViewController not playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

I'll keep it simple, heres the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
VideoEntry *entry = [videoEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:entry.url] completeBlock:^(NSDictionary *videoDictionary, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *urls = [videoDictionary allValues];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urls objectAtIndex:0]];
    [mp.moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
    [mp.moviePlayer setContentURL:url];
    [mp.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [mp.moviePlayer play];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
}];
```

}

mp is a MPMoviePlayerViewController. The view controller is presented but then the movie doesn't start, it just says "Loading..." and before you ask I'm 100% sure the links work.

Thanks!

Comment: are u using ARC ?How did u instantiate your mp ?

Comment: I use ARC, I just made a nonatomic,strong property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the completion block isn't called on the main thread. 
You can solve by force the execution of your code on the main thread:

```
[HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:entry.url]
                            completeBlock:^(NSDictionary *videoDictionary, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        NSArray *urls = [videoDictionary allValues];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urls objectAtIndex:0]];
        [mp.moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
        [mp.moviePlayer setContentURL:url];
        [mp.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [mp.moviePlayer play];
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
    });
}];
```